# assetic dump is not dumping on correct path

Tags: symfony, deployment, build, assetic

issue : In my build.xml i want to do local-deploy to a specific folder but it is somehow not deploying
        properly,sometime assetic:dump does on correct folder and sometime it is doing on wrong 
        folder.e.g. is below

assetic:dump to wrong folder

**local-deploy:**

```
          11:06:17      [mkdir] Created dir: /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
 11:06:17      [echo] Moving project to /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
 11:06:20      [copy] Copying 11921 files to /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
 11:06:22      [copy] Copied 2358 empty directories to 105 empty directories  
                      under /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
 11:06:22      [echo] Installing web assets
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets using the hard copy option
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle 
                into web/bundles/framework
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for JordiLlonch\Bundle\CrudGeneratorBundle into web/bundles/jordillonchcrudgenerator
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\EconecomBundle into web/bundles/niwaeconecom
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UsermanagementBundle into web/bundles/niwausermanagement
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UserinterfaceBundle into web/bundles/niwauserinterface
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UtilitiesBundle into web/bundles/niwautilities
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ForecastRestBundle into web/bundles/niwaforecastrest
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ForecastUIBundle into web/bundles/niwaforecastui
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ContentAPIBundle into web/bundles/niwacontentapi
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
 11:06:26      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ThirdPartyBundle into web/bundles/niwathirdparty
 11:06:27      [exec] Dumping all test assets.
 11:06:27      [exec] Debug mode is on.
 11:06:27      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec]                                                                                                                                 
 11:06:32      [exec]   [RuntimeException]                                                                                                            
 11:06:32      [exec]   The source file "/repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/bundles/niwaeconecom/less/main.less" does not exist.  
 11:06:32      [exec]                                                                                                                                 
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] assetic:dump [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] 
 11:06:32      [exec] 11:06:31 [file+] /repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/js/b2dccab.js
 11:06:32      [exec] 11:06:31 [file+] /repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/js/b2dccab_passwordCheck_1.js
 11:06:32      [exec] 11:06:31 [file+] /repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/js/b2dccab_account_2.js
 11:06:32      [exec] 11:06:31 [file+] /repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/js/3734ff1.js
 11:06:32      [exec] 11:06:31 [file+] /repository/jenkins/jobs/forecast/workspace/app/../web/js/3734ff1_common_1.js
```

**It suppose to go to this folder :**

```
[mkdir] Created dir: /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
15:31:40      [echo] Moving project to /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
15:31:42      [copy] Copying 10719 files to /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
15:31:45      [copy] Copied 2089 empty directories to 112 empty directories under /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest
15:31:45      [echo] Installing web assets
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets using the hard copy option
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets for JordiLlonch\Bundle\CrudGeneratorBundle into web/bundles/jordillonchcrudgenerator
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\EconecomBundle into web/bundles/niwaeconecom
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UsermanagementBundle into web/bundles/niwausermanagement
15:31:49      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UserinterfaceBundle into web/bundles/niwauserinterface
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\UtilitiesBundle into web/bundles/niwautilities
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ForecastRestBundle into web/bundles/niwaforecastrest
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ForecastUIBundle into web/bundles/niwaforecastui
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ContentAPIBundle into web/bundles/niwacontentapi
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
15:31:50      [exec] Installing assets for Niwa\ThirdPartyBundle into web/bundles/niwathirdparty
15:31:53      [exec] Dumping all test assets.
15:31:53      [exec] Debug mode is on.
15:31:53      [exec] 
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [dir+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/83950ce.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/83950ce_login_1.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/css/8892858.css
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/css/8892858_bootstrap_1.css
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/css/8892858_bootstrap-theme_2.css
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/b2dccab.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/b2dccab_passwordCheck_1.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/b2dccab_account_2.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/f9999e4.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/f9999e4_review_1.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/6917cbd.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/6917cbd_configure_1.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/f3d4596.js
15:31:57      [exec] 15:31:57 [file+] /srv/www/vhosts/forecast.autotest/app/../web/js/f3d4596_complete_1.js
```

***so basically it suppose to go to /srv/www/vhosts/... but sometime it goes to /repository/jenkins/jobs/...***

**my config.yml file is as below:**

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        less:
            node: %node%
            node_paths: %node_paths%
            apply_to: "\.less$"
    cssrewrite: ~
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: %uglify_path%
```

the command i use to dump is :

```
 <echo message="Installing web assets" />
<exec dir="srv/www/vhosts/forecast.${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}" executable="php"     
failonerror="false">
 <arg line="app/console assets:install web" />
</exec>
```

Comment: What exact command line do you use to invoke `assetic:dump`?

Comment: <echo message="Installing web assets" />
      <exec dir="srv/www/vhosts/forecast.${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}"  executable="php"     
    failonerror="false">
     <arg line="app/console assets:install web" />
    </exec>

Comment: `assets:install` !== `assetic:dump`.

Comment: well i am doing both first doing assets:install then assetic:dump after that with --env=test.